# hibernate.cfg.xml not found error while running on server

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

project run on local machine, but after deploy on server get hibernate.cfg.xml not found error.same war file deploy on local machine tomcat it work.

```
2015-07-13 07:00:00 ERROR JobRunShell:211 - Job grpPM.jobPM threw an unhandled Exception: 
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2095)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2076)
    at hibernet.HibernateConnection.getInstance(HibernateConnection.java:32)
    at hibernet.HibernateData.getConnection(HibernateData.java:45)
    at stockRefresh.Script330.runScript(Script330.java:34)
    at StockRefresh330.execute(StockRefresh330.java:13)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
2015-07-13 07:00:00 ERROR ErrorLogger:2425 - Job (grpPM.jobPM threw an exception.
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate.cfg.xml not found]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2095)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2076)
    at hibernet.HibernateConnection.getInstance(HibernateConnection.java:32)
    at hibernet.HibernateData.getConnection(HibernateData.java:45)
    at stockRefresh.Script330.runScript(Script330.java:34)
    at StockRefresh330.execute(StockRefresh330.java:13)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
```

Comment: Where did you place your hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: in src folder.it work fine on local machine not work after deploy on server

Answer (score 0):

Put your hibernate.cfg.xml in your classpath. and if you don't want, use the below to get context of your XML file.

Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");//Here you can give your exact path w.r.t your project`

Comment: Then most probably check with your deployment team if they are maintaining the project structure.

Comment: Can you place your java code where you are getting the config file?

Comment: if(instance == null)
  {
   config = new Configuration().configure("Hibernate.cfg.xml");

Comment: It looks good, then you can just cross check few things, 1. Check if your cfg file name is same and 2. if it is same then you need to make sure it's in your classpath. If it's working in your local and not in your server you can do the any of the below thing ;- 1. put your config file in resource and then in configure give your full path, OR 2. In your manifest file you can give Class-Path: Hibernate.cfg.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `hibernate.cfg.xml` under `src/main/resources` if the file is the same folder as your Java files your build system may not copy it.